# Notepad++ html tag / string (a href) remove

Tags: html, replace, notepad++

Have 12.000 links which I want delete and only display the Linktext over Notepad

from

```
<A HREF="/" CLASS="size0verdgr">HOME</A>
```

to
HOME

from

```
<A HREF="/NEW/" target="_blank">NEW</A>
```

to 
NEW

I can Use:

```
<a href="[^"]*" CLASS="[^"]*">
```

but there I can only delete the first part of the tag.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the Replace interface (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). Change the *search mode* to "Regular Expression".

In the *search field* you enter the following pattern,

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>
```

It will match any a-tag, and the text in between the tags you can call in the *replace field* by entering,

`\1`

Finally, press *Replace All* and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding you want to replace the entire line

```
<A HREF="/NEW/" target="_blank">NEW</A>
```

with

```
NEW
```

*nix wins

```
sed -i 's/<A HREF.\+>\(.\+\)<\/A>/\1/' test.txt
```

Thats the regex pattern so you can run that on any search and replace regex editor. Depending on the editor you may need to remove some back slashes or replace \1 with &1

Comment: Don´t understand what you mean. Which I integrate in search in which in replace.

Only want to delete the <a href> tag. only want to display the linkword without links.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner.
I do realize what you want to do however I don't know of a way to do this on notepad++ if you have access to a unix/linux box and put the file on there. name test.txt and run the following command final.txt will contain the format you want.

sed -i 's/<A HREF.\+>\(.\+\)<\/A>/\1/' test.txt > final.txt